# What database parameter do I have to check in Oracle for default DATE parameter in a function?

Tags: javascript, oracle, node-oracledb

I have the following strange issue. I have the following procedure, in a package:

```
PROCEDURE createSmth (p_param1        IN     VARCHAR2,
                      p_param2        IN     NUMBER,
                      p_param3        IN     DATE,
                      p_param4        IN     DATE,
                      p_description   IN     VARCHAR2,
                      p_last_login    IN     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                      o_sid           OUT    NUMBER,
                      p_ret           OUT    NUMBER,
                      p_mess          OUT    VARCHAR2);
```

The application that is calling this procedure is using "oracledb": "^4.2.0".
The following is a dev log (formatted for easier read):

```
DBService: calling stored procedure 'BEGIN pkg.createSmth(
:p_param1, 
:p_param2, 
:p_param3, 
:p_param4, 
:p_description, 
:p_last_login, 
:o_sid, 
:p_ret, 
:p_mess); END;' 

with bindings 

[{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"test"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2010,"val":37},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"01/06/2020"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"03/06/2020"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"test233"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"admin"},
{"dir":3003,"type":2010},
{"dir":3003,"type":2010},
{"dir":3003,"type":2001}]

pkg.createSmth: get connection - 1 ms
pkg.createSmth: execute statement - 225 ms
pkg.createSmth: get values - 225 ms
```

The following, happens in production (formatted for easier read):

```
DBService: calling stored procedure 'BEGIN pkg.createSmth(
:p_param1, 
:p_param2, 
:p_param3, 
:p_param4, 
:p_description, 
:p_last_login, 
:o_sid, 
:p_ret, 
:p_mess); END;' 

with bindings 

[{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"test"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2010,"val":37},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"01/06/2020"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"03/06/2020"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"test233"},
{"dir":3001,"type":2001,"val":"admin"},
{"dir":3003,"type":2010},
{"dir":3003,"type":2010},
{"dir":3003,"type":2001}]

pkg.createSmth: get connection - 0 ms
Unexpected DB error
undefined: Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 1, trace: Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

On both dev and prod, the oracledb type for the IN parameters is set to STRING.

Doing `select sysdate from dual` returns the same date format on both DBs: `16-JUN-20`.

So, any hint on solving this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If the procedure expects `DATE`, don't provide a **STRING**.

This is string:

```
'01/06/2020'
```

These are dates:

```
date '2020-06-01'
to_date('01/06/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Pick an option which suits you best; if you'll always pass date (without a time component), date literal (which is always in format `date 'yyyy-mm-dd'`) is OK. If you'll be passing time, then `to_date` (with appropriate format mask) might be a better choice.

Comment: Procedure parameter is DATE. oracle-db type is STRING.
For mapping between node-oracledb types and Oracle types, please check http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-313-node-oracledb-type-constants

Answer (score 0):

There can be many causes for this error. It can be `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter or a format parameter in `TO_DATE` function for example.

You need to analyze the code to fix this issue.

Example:

```
SQL> show parameter nls_date_format

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
nls_date_format              string  DD/MM/YYYY
SQL> select to_date('06/16/2020') from dual;
select to_date('06/16/2020') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month


SQL> select to_date('16/06/2020') from dual;

TO_DATE('1
----------
16/06/2020

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `01/06/2020` use

- `to_date('01/06/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')` or
- `date '2020-06-01'` -- date literal

To know the date format that is used by your session/database you can use the `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS` or `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` view (Parameter name: `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` ). But it is recommended to use the specific format with `to_date` or `date literal` as `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` may change over time and your code will not work.

Comment: Not using either of them in dev and it works as it should

Comment: Then in Dev, `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` that your session is using must be `dd/mm/yyyy` which is different than Prod so you are facing the issue in Prod. That is why it is recommended to always use the `to_date` or `date literal` to create the date as mentioned in the answer.